# Solution to simple first-order partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a general solution for first-order partial differential equations of the form

$$m(x) \partial_x f(x,y) =  n(y) \partial_y f(x,y)$$

for given $m(x),n(y)$ and reasonable boundary conditions (e.g. $f(x,0)=0$ etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the variables in $x$ and $y$, i.e., $\tilde x =\tilde x(x)$ and $\tilde y = \tilde y(y)$ to make $m(x) = n(y) = 1$. Then equation can be written as

$
\partial_{\tilde x}f  =\partial_{\tilde y}f. 
$

The equation above is equivalent to that $f= f(\tilde x+ \tilde y)$.

Comment: This won't work if $m$ and/or $n$ vanish at some points of the domain, and the OP may be concerned about these cases.

Comment: Robert, thanks for your comment! This is the first step I would like to try. Assuming that the zeros of $m(x)$ and $n(y)$ are discrete, it will give solutions at different pieces. I am not sure there is any general statement I can make given no information of $m$ and $n$.